# JavaScript global variable not changed

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Why can I add something to a global declared array, but not change the value of the variable itself?

This works:

```js
var test = [5, 5];
function a(test) {
  test.push(8);
}
a(test);
console.log(test);
//expected: [5, 5, 8]
```

But this doesn't:

```js
var test = [5, 5];
function a(test) {
  test = 8;
}
a(test);
console.log(test);
//expected: 8 but is [5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code, you are passing a the reference of your `array` object as an argument to the function `a`. And you are cutting off the reference's connection inside of that function by assigning a new `primitive value` to the variable which holds the `reference`. Hence the array in the global scope won't get affected at all.

This case is similar to,

```
var x = [];
var y = x; //setting the reference of the object x to y
y = 10; //cutting off the connection to the reference.

console.log(y); //10
console.log(x); //[]
```

If you do not replace the reference with a primitive value then,

```
var x = [];
var y = x; //setting the reference of the object x to y
y.push(10);

console.log(y); //[10]
console.log(x); //[10]
console.log(x == y); //true
```

Basically using a value in global scope would cause unnecessary conflicts. Still if you want to achieve what you want to do, then remove the parameter of the function `a`.

```
var test = [5, 5];
function a() {
  test = 8;
}
a();
console.log(test); //8
```

Comment: This makes sense but how would I solve it? I need to change the value of the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because in the second snippet you changed the object (a primitive value) it was pointing to which had the local scope.

```
test = 8; // it is no longer pointing to the earlier object in memory so that object value has not changed, just that this reference is pointing to new object.
```

After this method `a()` was finished it lost the object which was in local scope and regained the one which was in outside scope.

If you want to change the value of `test` and while passing the value of the array then

```
var test = [5, 5];
function a(test) {
  test.splice(0,test.length);
  test.push(8)
}
a(test);
console.log(test);
```

This will first clear the `test` array and push 8 into it.